# Is there time series chart on fl_chart or is there any way to make line_chart a time series one?

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

Using line charts i cannot display time series data correctly. Is there a way to make it happen using any packages other than syncfusion_flutter_charts and charts_flutter.

Here is the code I tried. But it results in incorrect graph.
[image]

Here is the expected output
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class FlChartExample extends StatelessWidget {
  FlChartExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  List<SalesDataPair> sales = [
    SalesDataPair( DateTime(2017, 9, 20), 25),
    SalesDataPair( DateTime(2017, 9, 24), 50),
    SalesDataPair( DateTime(2017, 10, 3), 100),
    SalesDataPair( DateTime(2017, 10, 11), 75),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<FlSpot> dummyData1 = List.generate(4, (index) {
      return FlSpot(sales[index].date.day.toDouble(), sales[index].amount);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: LineChart(
            LineChartData(
              borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
              lineBarsData: [
                LineChartBarData(
                  spots: dummyData1,
                  isCurved: false,
                  barWidth: 3,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SalesDataPair {
  SalesDataPair(this.date, this.amount);
  final DateTime date;
  final double amount;
}
```

I understood why the graph is wrongly displayed.

Comment: Share your desired output UI snippet

Comment: added screenshots